# Hardhat cannot deploy contract to Parachain Frontier EVM - execution fatal: Other("")

Tags: hardhat

My team's parachain is using Frontier Ethereum EVM.

That is similar to the EVM in Moombean
https://docs.moonbeam.network/builders/build/eth-api/dev-env/hardhat/

My hardhat.config.ts:

```
    parachain: {
      url: "http://127.0.0.1:6969",
      chainId: 1345,
      gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits("10", "gwei").toNumber(),
      gas: 2100000,
      accounts: [
        `${DEPLOYER_PRIVATE_KEY}`,
        `${USER1PK}`,
        `${USER2PK}`
      ],
    },
```

That URL `http://127.0.0.1:6969` is good because I can connect MetaMask to my parachain with it, then send some tokens.

I have tested all contracts with test files. No problem at all.

I can also deploy all of them in Hardhat's local EVM via

```
in terminal 1: $ npx hardhat node
in terminal 2: $ npx hardhat run --network localhost scripts/deployERC20.ts
```

All deployment was successful.

But when I use Hardhat to deploy contracts onto my parachain:

```
$ npx hardhat run --network parachain scripts/deployERC20.ts
```

I got this error:

```
ProviderError: execution fatal: Other("")
    at HttpProvider.request (/mnt/sda4/0Programming/Ethereum/1aTokenStandards/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/http.ts:78:19)
    at LocalAccountsProvider.request (/mnt/sda4/0Programming/Ethereum/1aTokenStandards/node_modules/hardhat/src/internal/core/providers/accounts.ts:188:34)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async EthersProviderWrapper.send (/mnt/sda4/0Programming/Ethereum/1aTokenStandards/node_modules/@nomiclabs/hardhat-ethers/src/internal/ethers-provider-wrapper.ts:13:20)
```

also if I try to deploy via Remix:

```
"code": -32603, "message": "execution fatal: Other(\"\")"
```

See reference: https://mirror.xyz/apecoder.eth/sEIg2H84JeMStwUsqv_T0HeWRBufkZSi-piQysch3VU

[Update] Hardhat cannot deploy, but Remix can deploy and invoke functions if we ignore warnings, but reading values from contracts cannot be done. It seems the RPC code for EVM is not working...

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to deploy Ethereum smart contracts onto a Polkadot parachain.
The RPC functions did not get hooked up properly... see https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3796/how-to-make-a-parachain-project-that-uses-frontier-as-a-dependency/3824#3824